# HOw can i bing an image in dropdown list in mvc 5 asp.net

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a drop down list which listingfew data. But now along with Texts that displaying, i need to display an image also along with the text.

my code is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.ID,
            new SelectList(Model.CourseCollection, "ID", "Title"),
   "Create New Course", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

i tried to create a variable and binding an image path to that and calling it along with "Title" but it return errors.

Any help would be highly appreciated....plss

Comment: what error did you get, and what else have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried 
`var img="image path";
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.ID,
            new SelectList(Model.CourseCollection, "ID", "Title" + img),
   "Create New Course", new { @class = "form-control" })`